# AsyncTask class in differents activities?

Tags: android, mysql, class

is possible to use a connection class (AsyncTask) in different classes?

For example, I have the following code in my MainActivity, but I want to use it in differents Activities, how can I use it being a secondary thread?:

```
public class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String resultadoConexion;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Connection conn;
                       try {

                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXX?user=XXXX&password=XXXX");
                            Log.i("Exito","Conexion a la base de datos realizada con exito");

                           resultadoConexion = "Conectado";
                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
{
                            resultadoConexion = "Error al conectar";
                            Log.i("ErrorBBDD", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        return resultadoConexion;
    }

    //Metodo que ejecuta la tarea del hilo
    public void Conectar() {
        Connect task = new Connect();
        task.execute();
    }

    //Creamos el metodo setText para poder asignar dentro del hilo secundario
    private void setText(final TextView text, final String value)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
                text.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Place the inline class in a seperate class file and reuse it.

ConnectAsyncTask.class

```
public class ConnectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String resultadoConexion;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Connection conn;
                       try {

                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXX?user=XXXX&password=XXXX");
                            Log.i("Exito","Conexion a la base de datos realizada con exito");

                           resultadoConexion = "Conectado";
                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
{
                            resultadoConexion = "Error al conectar";
                            Log.i("ErrorBBDD", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        return resultadoConexion;
    }

    //Metodo que ejecuta la tarea del hilo
    public void Conectar() {
        Connect task = new Connect();
        task.execute();
    }

    //Creamos el metodo setText para poder asignar dentro del hilo secundario
    private void setText(final TextView text, final String value)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
                text.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }
```

Then use it at any place you want:

MyActivity1:

```
import package...ConnectAsyncTask;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstance) {
  new ConnectAsyncTask().execute(url);
}
```

MyActivity2:

```
import package...ConnectAsyncTask;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstance) {
  new ConnectAsyncTask().execute(url);
}
```

Or directly reuse the innerclass of your activity. For example your Activity name is MyActivity then you can get an instance of the connect task like so:

```
new MyActivity.Connect()
```

Comment: Ok, now it´s working properly but, do I have to call this method in every different activity or is already connected to the database having done it in the main activity?

Comment: The async task is for doing something not for initializing. When your task has finished, the garbage collector will remove it from RAM including your connection. Place your connection handling i a simple class. Handle this class for example as a singleton in your application context, reuse then the connection in your async tasks to do work on.